# Model Binder issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-binding

I have a read-only property on a viewmodel that calculates a value from various other properties. I do not want it to be read by the model binder on posts because not all of the source properties are available.

```
public class MyView
{
     public int MyReadOnlyProperty
     {
         get 
         {
             int result;
             //do stuff 
             return result;
         }
     }
}
```

I have added a `[Bind(Exclude)]` attribute to the controller method like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Exclude = "MyReadOnlyProperty")]MyView viewModel)
{
}
```

However, the binder still reads the excluded property. So when I post back to the above controller method, the `MyReadOnlyProperty` getter is executed; but *before* the controller method is called. It seems strange that the binder is reading properties on a post: I would expect it only to be setting them using form values.

Can anyone tell me how to avoid this?

Comment: What do you mean binder still read the excluded property? Can you give a concrete example and how your `MyView` model is being bound?

Comment: That's tuff. I would not use that as my view-model if possible. create a View-Model that gets its data from this object.

Comment: @manojlds, I have explained in the question that the MyReadOnlyProperty getter code is executed by the MVC framework after posting, but before the controller method is executed.

Comment: @DaveA, agreed that would be one solution, but to avoid creating extra viewmodels, I'd first like to see if I can solve it another way.

Comment: @PaulTaylor So you want to remove `MyReadOnlyProperty` from ModelState ?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try like this :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(MyView viewModel)
{
   ModelState.Remove("MyReadOnlyProperty");
}
```

Hope it helps

---

**Edit**

```
[Bindable(false)]
public int MyReadOnlyProperty
     {
         get 
         {
             int result;
             //do stuff 
             return result;
         }
     }
```

Comment: thanks, but that won't work because MyReadOnlyProperty is called *before* the controller action.

Comment: Where is it gettting called ? What do you want to acheive in you `Create` controller ? Sorry for my questions I'm bit confused

Comment: what the Create method does is irrelevant, the binder calls the viewmodel property during binding, before the controller method is called. That's what I want to avoid.

Comment: ok, then try like this in your model class--  `[Bindable(false)]public int MyReadOnlyProperty{get;set;}`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that would work only if I never want the property bound. Unfortunately, in some contexts I do. Will have to take the hit and develop a separate view model, I think.